# What's special about (x'x-x'Proj(w)x)?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, linear-model, matrix, determinant

I'm working on my homework and I keep seeing something like $$(x'x-x'W(W'W)^{-1}W'x)$$

I know that $W(W'W)^{-1}W'$ is the projection matrix, but what is so special about subtracting those two inner products?

---

a little context...

Let $X=[x_0,x_1,...,x_{k-1},x_k]=[W,x_k]$ and let $r(X)=k+1$, 
show that 
$$det(X'X)=det(W'W)(x_k'x_k-x_k'W(W'W)^{-1}W'x_k)$$

Comment: To get superscripts of more than 1 character, wrap the superscript in `{ }`, i.e. `W^{-1}` to give $W^{-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, if you call $p_S(X)$ an orthogonal projector of $X$ on the subspace $S$, $X-p_S(X)$ is orthogonal to every vector of $S$.

On the other hand, for any $Y\in S$, $Y-p_S(Y)=0$.

As for the exercise, you should have a look at [calculating determinants of block matrices](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.4379.pdf)